# How can we check that which image in imageview is being called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I am having 2 imageviews with image in it. I want that when I click on the first image the image should get selected and if it is selected it should return me value TRUE or 1 that should be saved in sqlite database. How is this possible?

Comment: you can use touch methods for implementing this

Comment: by using touch methods u will get which image view is touched .. and upon selection get image from image view and dump image data into file instead of database.

Comment: actually i cant get u properly can u please explain me in detail.thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You go with Touch events.Capture the touch points and perform your actions.Here I will give u a sample structure to do this,

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    CGPoint location= [touch locationInView:self.view];

    if(CGRectContainsPoint(firstImage.frame, location)) {
        //set some flag like
        selectionFlag=1;        }
    else if(CGRectContainsPoint(secImage.frame, location)){
        selectionFlag=2;        }
    }

    - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { 

        UITouch  *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject]; 
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];

        if(CGRectContainsPoint(firstImage.frame, location)) {   
            if(selectionflag==1) {
                //do ur db actions              }
        }
        else if(CGRectContainsPoint(secImage.frame, location))  {       
            if(selectionflag==2) {
            //do ur db actions                }
        }
        selectionflag=0; 
    }
```

Comment: hi, i am having one doubt first image and secImage are imageviews or image objects

Answer (score 1):

By using UITouch class methods you will get which image view is touched, or you can put imageview inside button then you will get click event.

Answer (score 0):

first do

```
[self.*yourimageViewname* setUserEnteractionEnabled:YES];
BOOL select1,secelect2;
select1=NO;
select2=NO;
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {

 UITouch *touch=[touches anyObject];
 CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
//give the beginning and ending x and y points in condition to check which imageView is taped

 if(touchLocation.x>1 && touchLocation.x<116 && touchLocation.y>133 && touchLocation.y<233)
 {
select1=YES;
}
else if(touchLocation.x>120 && touchLocation.x<300 && touchLocation.y>133 && touchLocation.y<233)
 {
select2=YES;
} 
}

 - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {
  }
```

On the condition which boolean variable is true you can save or whatever you want to do further coding your application.

Comment: you are correct ,but i want to save my values in database.in sqlite database boolean values cannot be binded.Thanks

Comment: no now can save your values in nsstring or somewhat else based on your boolean conditions like take two integer and pass 1 if boolean is yes and 0 if boolean is no.

Comment: no now can save your values in nsstring or somewhat else based on your boolean conditions like take two integer and pass 1 if boolean is yes and 0 if boolean is no.

Answer (score 0):

Using the touches is one way as explained in the answers below. If you have just two imageview you can also try to have two custom transparent buttons on top of that imageview and therefore you can easily know which image is touched based on the tag you give for the buttons.

Comment: but how to save the value of selected button on the sqlite database.Could u please help me on that.

Comment: based on the button you can save the image

Answer (score 0):

What you could also do is create two buttons (instead of UIImageViews) that have images. They should display roughly the same (you could even disable the touch states, etc). And you get UIResponder events for free (as in; you can target the action to a selector).

UPDATE: here's roughly how (didn't bother configuring the buttons though).

```
UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button1 setImage:yourImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTouched:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

// .. now create a second button .. //
```

And your button will go to the following method when touched:

```
- (void)buttonTouched:(id)sender
{
   // .. add your stuff to your database .. //
   // .. you can identify your button by sender, or give the button a tag (number) to identify it .. /
}
```